# Incorrect password passed to LogonUser() but the Active Directory account is not locked as expected

Tags: c++, winapi, active-directory

I have Active directory "number of logon retries" = 3. We call 
[LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function 5 times with the wrong password. After that I call `LogonUser` with right password and it works, and the user can login.

Why is the account not locked out?

Comment: What are you passing for dwLogonType and dwLogonProvider?

Comment: LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE and LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,

Comment: Do you use the UPN format `lpszUsername` or set `lpszDomain` ?

Comment: yes... I post bug into ms... problems with cache on AD controller side... I cant write more, because it's security issue ))

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how you call `LogonUser`.  If you do not specify a domain name, through either the `lpszDomain` parameter or by specifying the `lpszUsername` in the [UPN format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_user_principal_name_gly) then you will attempting to login on the local machine.

Windows clients [store cached credentials](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994565%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for domain logins for situations where the Active Directory server is not available.  In this case, the cached credentials will allow the user to logon to the local machine.

> Cached credentials are used when using domain credentials for authentication to a computer that is not connected to a domain controller. Each time a domain user logs on, the operating system generates the cached credentials and stores them in the Security hive of the operating system.

According to Microsoft's [Account Lockout Policy Technical Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994566%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> Account lockout policies apply to domain accounts. Account lockout is an interaction between a client computer and a domain controller and implements the following process:

Without seeing your code, I suspect that the login attempts occur against the local machine, not the domain.  These don't count towards the lockout policy.  This allows the user to logon to the domain without a problem.

Comment: how to reset "Cached credentials"?

Comment: @kain64b Try this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15574/how-do-i-clear-cached-credentials-from-my-windows-profile

Comment: "LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK
This logon type is intended for high performance servers to authenticate plaintext passwords. The LogonUser function does not cache credentials for this logon type."
doesnt work...
It is MS bug with the "credentials cache"... I cant specify domain for the "crossdomain user authentication"...

Comment: @kain64b if you're not specifying the domain how will it know you've tried to login with incorrect credentials?