# Will repeatedly calling LogonUser from Delphi with LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK cause the account to be locked?

Tags: delphi, winapi

When using `LogonUser()` with `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK` to validate a user's Windows login and password, it does not seem to cause their account to be locked even if the wrong password is checked more times than the user's security policy allows.

There is a similar question:

[Incorrect password passed to LogonUser() but the Active Directory account is not locked as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587715)

But in their case, they were using `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` instead.

In my case, the domain controller is available to authenticate the logon, but it is not clear from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184.aspx) whether using `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK` means it does not authenticate with the domain controller, only that it will not cache the credentials if they are correct.

What I'm looking for is a policy setting that will lock a Windows domain account if `LogonUser()` is used with the wrong password too many times.

**EDIT:** Additional information to help clarify the situation.

When calling `LoginUser()` on my XE2 development machine with the correct *domain\user* but incorrect *password*, the result is false. Calling `SysUtils.SysErrorMessage(System.GetLastError)` gives me:

> The operation completed successfully

The same test performed on any of the machines at the client site shows:

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Continuing the test on any of their machines eventually has it reporting:

> The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to

What I am trying to determine is why that client is behaving differently, as we'd like to have systems on our domain also lock accounts. Perhaps it is a property of the Windows account?

Comment: I think there must be something wrong with the way you're checking the error code - if the call fails, the error code should never be zero.  (I suspect that the reason the account isn't being locked is that the logon attempt is failing before it gets as far as checking the password.  But without the actual error code, that's pure guesswork.)  I can confirm that using the `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK` logon type does not prevent the system from attempting to authenticate against a domain controller.  I'm unsure whether it can succeed against cached credentials if the domain controller isn't there.

Comment: (Note that the line saying "LogonUser does not cache credentials for this logon type" is talking about a different sort of cached credential.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The policy setting you are looking for is the [Account Lockout Threshold](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994574(v=ws.11).aspx).

I don't believe this has anything what-so-ever to do with the fact that Delphi is the language involved in calling the API.  This is purely a Windows API / security policy question.

Comment: You are correct. The development domain had the threshold set to 0. That has now been fixed and we see the same result as the client.